# Connecting to MongoDB hosted on Amazon EC2 (using PyMongo)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I'm having trouble remotely connecting to my MongoDB instance; I've deployed it using the [MongoDB AWS Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mongodb-on-the-aws-cloud-new-quick-start-reference-deployment/), and can connect via SSH as per the "Testing" section of the Quick Start guide.

However, when trying to connect remotely (I'm using the PyMongo driver), I run into a `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out` error.

I've tried setting `bind_ip` to `0.0.0.0` as well as an Elastic IP to the VPC instance that the mongod is running on, but to no avail. In fact, even pinging the EIP leads to a timeout (although pinging the NAT instance doesn't).

With PyMongo I've tried both DNS's, with and without SSL. I can successfully connect to MongoDB on `localhost`.

These are the security groups for the VPC: [AWS security groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyXGU.png)

If anyone has a clue on what I might be doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it; I've been struggling with this for over a day now. Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -an` on the instance? Also, you aren't allowing ICMP traffic in that security group which explains why your pings are dying.

Comment: you should connect to the public IP of the server, the EIP nor the DC (internal) address will work externally

Comment: You should also make MongoDB bc on that IP

Comment: Of course, in reality, for security reasons you don't. But just to get things set up it is fine

Comment: @ydaetskcoR These are the outputs of `netstat -an` on the public subnet (http://i.imgur.com/f5RAu4T.png) and the VPC instance (http://i.imgur.com/CGyyNS3.png) respectively. I tried allowing all ICMP on the VPC instance but my pings are still dying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try setting up MongoDB on the public subnet to get started. How would you connect to the VPC though, assuming you wanted that additional security?

Comment: You would never directly connect to mongodb on the VPC. You would only ever access third party through SSH or a secure program running on the internal network alongside the VPC.